# Calculator in Python can't print out the result I want

Tags: python

I wanted to create this calculator in Python and I had some problems when it printed out. The problem was that everytime that I ran the program it printed out Check for errors. When I removed it, it started to print me out numbers put together. For example 1 + 2 = 12 or 2 + 5= 25, etc.This thing happened only when I tried to add two numbers, when I tried multiplying, subtracting or dividing it didn't print out anything. This is my code:

```
print ("Enter your first number")
num1 = input()
print("Enter your second number") 
num2 = input()
print("Enter operation")
operation = input()
if operation is "+":
print(num1 + num2)
elif operation is "*":
print(num1 * num2)
elif operation is "/":
print(num1 / num2)
elif operation is "-":
print(num1 - num2)
else:
print("Check for errors")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Comment: Try with `==` instead of `is`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fjoni Yzeiri: Hi folk,

This is a common issue when starting with Python, as you don't declare the variable type of the input, it will save it as a `String`, so if you concatenate (`+` in Python) it will concatenate the two Inputs.

To solve this you have to explicitly cast this values into `Integers`, it means:

```
print ("Enter your first number")
num1 = int(input()) # Cast to int here
print("Enter your second number") 
num2 = int(input()) # Cast to int here
print("Enter operation")
operation = input()
if operation is "+":
print(num1 + num2)
elif operation is "*":
print(num1 * num2)
elif operation is "/":
print(num1 / num2)
elif operation is "-":
print(num1 - num2)
else:
print("Check for errors")
```

Of course, this is a very simple use case, if you want to learn a bit more, try to caught the exception when it tries to cast a non-integer string. It will teach you nice stuff ;)

Comment: Thanks. I was writing the answer somone gave me while you wrote your answer at the same time xD

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be using `==` instead of `is` to compare string literals with a variable.  I'd expect your usage to always return false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now. Someone posted the answer but he deleted it I think and I couldn't upvote it. I needed to change

```
num1 = input()
```

to

```
num1 = int(input())
```